# Target Display Mode not working when no keyboard present

Tags: mac, keyboard, applescript

When I try to use some kind of command + f2 command either via applescript or screen share, it never works when the keyboard is no longer present.

Example, I have an iMac and a laptop where the laptop is the host the the iMac is being put into TDM. If I run the script while the wireless keyboard/mouse is connected to the iMac everything is fine. If I first disconnect the keyboard and run the the script via ssh from the host or even do a full screenshare and try to run the command, it does not work without a connected keyboard. That's important - event remotely the the script works when there's a keyboard present on the slave machine but if it's not present, the script no longer works.

All of this is ultimately present in my particular pain point of when the machine goes to sleep it disconnects TDM and I have no way to reconnect without first giving the keyboard and mouse back to the iMac.

Appreciate any insight on this.

Bonus points to anyone that can also suggest an applescripty way to force a machine to look for a keyboard and mouse via applescript or other. I'd like to incorporate that into my workflow. Example - run command "disconnect" and it briefly powers down bluetooth locally and forces a new search remotely.
The bluetooth toggle is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Same situation here. Now my way is first let keyboard connect to the iMac and put it into TDM. Second , use VNC connect the iMac and turn off its bluetooth, so that my macbook can connect to the bluetooth keyboard. Also you can write a shell script to turn on/off the bluetooth. for now I didn't find any command or application can force the mac into TDM。 I can't believe when apple develop this function they ignore the requirement like this. Wish anyone can show us a better way to do this.